# Image grid gallery on Shopify - images not showing

Tags: html, shopify

As Shopify doesn't do a grid gallery anymore, I had to source code for how to manually add this section back in. I thought I finally got the code going but when the images are uploaded, they dont appear. Even though it shows the image has on the right hand side.

Not sure what I'm missing here...

I've had a look through the code over and over and cant figure out why the images are not appearing once they are uploaded into each of the blocks. Hoping someone here can help me out.

[image]

```html
<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="featured-collections-section">
  <div class="wrapper">
    {% if section.settings.title != blank %}
      <div class="section-header text-center">
        <h2 class="h1 section-header__title">{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>
        <hr class="hr--small">
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="grid collection-grid">
      {% assign grid_item_width = "one-half medium--one-third large--one-third" %}
      {% if section.blocks.size == 1 %}
        {% assign grid_item_width = "one-whole" %}
      {% elsif section.blocks.size == 2 %}
        {% assign grid_item_width = "one-half medium--one-half large--one-half" %}
      {% endif %}
      
      {% for block in section.blocks %}
        <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }} collection-collage__item text-center" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
          <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}" class="collection-grid__item-link collection-collage__item-wrapper">
            {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
              <div class="collection-grid__item-overlay grid__image">{{ 'collection-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}</div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="collection-grid__item-overlay grid__image lazyload"
                   style="background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x' }});"
                   data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: block.settings.image %}"
                   data-sizes="auto"
                   data-parent-fit="cover">
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          </a>
        </div>

      {% endfor %}

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Images Gallery",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Heading",
      "default": "Images Gallery"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Images Gallery",
      "category": "Images"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "image",
      "name": "Image",
      "settings": [
        {
          "id": "image",
          "type": "image_picker",
          "label": "Image"
        },
        {
          "id": "link",
          "type": "url",
          "label": "Link"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```